# mat expansion panel component icon alignment issue

Tags: angular, angular-material

i using  component for collapsible menu but icon alignment not properly coming its align right side of text instead of left side, can any one suggest how to achieve this issue.

[image]

**using below code:**

```
<mat-expansion-panel class="mxSubMenuContainer">
            <mat-expansion-panel-header  expandedHeight="48px" collapsedHeight="48px">
              <md-icon class="mat-icon mat-list-icon material-icons">pages</md-icon>
              <mat-panel-title>
                    Personal data
              </mat-panel-title>
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>

            <a mat-list-item class="sidenav-link mat-list-item mat-ripple" >
                <div class="mat-list-item-content">
                    <div class="mat-list-item-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div>
                    <md-icon class="mat-icon mat-list-icon material-icons">pages</md-icon>
                    <div class="mat-list-text">
                      <span class="title mat-line" md-line="">Pages</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </a>
          </mat-expansion-panel>
```

**Expected UI**

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Material 2 Expansion panel's containers by default are using flexbox, so we need to use flexbox approach to align content and for this 'flex-basis' is the best way.

For example, override CSS in your component in this way:

```css
    mat-panel-title {
      flex-basis: 0;
    }
    mat-panel-description {
      flex-basis: 100%;
    }
```

I created example you were asking: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b8whsd?file=app%2Fexpansion-overview-example.css

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want to put the icon into the title. For example

```
<mat-expansion-panel class="mxSubMenuContainer">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header  expandedHeight="48px" collapsedHeight="48px">

          <mat-panel-title>
               <md-icon class="mat-icon mat-list-icon material-icons">pages</md-icon>
                Personal data
          </mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>

        <a mat-list-item class="sidenav-link mat-list-item mat-ripple" >
            <div class="mat-list-item-content">
                <div class="mat-list-item-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div>
                <md-icon class="mat-icon mat-list-icon material-icons">pages</md-icon>
                <div class="mat-list-text">
                  <span class="title mat-line" md-line="">Pages</span>
                </div>
              </div>
        </a></mat-expansion-panel>
```